# How to focus/select elements in HTML in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I use Angular to build my HTML webpage and I have HTML elements that count semantically as items/units, e.g. a list created by `*ngFor` where each item counts as an item/unit.

```
<div *ngFor="let foo of foos; ... " [class.selected]="currentSelectedDivIndex == i">
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
```

So a "unit" is the `div` container. I would like to make such item "selectable", which means it changes it's background color to indicate the selection status. And all of that works fine so far by using `[class.selected]` in combination with an index check.

But..

AFAIK only certain HTML elements can be focused/selected like buttons, text-fields, etc. What is a common approach to make my **own** elements selectable?

Currently I solved it on application level by attaching a `(click)` event to these elements which set one of the following variables:

```
currentSelectedDivIndex: number
leftImageIsSelected: boolean;
rightImageIsSelected: boolean;
```

But that doesn't feel correct. On a side note, there is this issue:

- Click on button
- Click on div element of list
- Press Enter ==> Triggers button again

The button was still selected by HTML in the background and is executed again although I clicked on the div container after the button click.

Comment: onClick set selectedItem === index from ngFor loop and check in ngClass that selectedItem equals to index

Comment: That's my current solution, but is this a common/correct approach? Also, do you have a solution for my "side note" problem?

Comment: Yes, what you're doing would be a pretty standard way of going about this for angular

Comment: You also must add <p (click)="onClick(index)"> {{foo}} </p> in .ts file onClick(index) { this.selectedItem = index;